# Edit a cart item attribute value for Woocommerce product variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-variations

My cart items has 1 attribute which is "size", how can I edit that?

```
.......
    ["attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["size"]=>
        string(1) "M"
      }
.......
```

Here's the ajax function I am editing the cart items with:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_updateCartItem', 'updateCartItem');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updateCartItem', 'updateCartItem');
function updateCartItem() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $key = $_POST['cart_item_key'];
    $pid = $_POST['product_id'];
    $qty = $_POST['quantity'];
    $sz = $_POST['variations_size'];

    WC()->cart->set_quantity( $key, $qty );

    $data = array("success"=>true,"data"=>array("cart_item_key"=>"$key","cart_item_subtotal"=>"<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\"><span class=\"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol\">$cs</span>&nbsp;$pc</span>","cart_total"=>"<span class=\"woocommerce-Price-amount amount\">&nbsp;".$woocommerce->cart->get_total()."</span>","cart_shipping"=>"Free","quantity"=>"$qty"));

    header('Content-Type: application/json charset=UTF-8');
    echo json_encode($data);
    die();
}
```

Comment: Is it a product variation (from a variable product) or a simple product?

Comment: yes from a variable product

Comment: i managed to edit the quantity with this:
$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[$key]['quantity'] = $qty;
but don't know how to do it for size attribute

Answer (score 0):

**First for quantity** `$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[$key]['quantity'] = $qty;` is totally outdated… Instead use the [`WC_Cart` method `set_quantity()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_set_quantity) this way:

```
 WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $qty );
```

---

#### To change product attributes in cart

**Variable products and product variations in cart**

Variable products are not editable as only a product variation from it can be added to cart…

The only way to edit an attribute for variation set in in the product variation is to use the following hooked function in `woocommerce_add_cart_item` filter hook.

The product attribute key slug to target always start with `attribute_pa_`.
The term to be replaced needs to be a slug (not a name).

Here for the product attribute "Size" we change it to "XXL" for example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'filter_add_cart_item', 10, 2 );
function filter_add_cart_item( $cart_item_data, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( isset($cart_item_data['variation']['attribute_pa_size']) ) {
        // Changing the term slug for product attribute "Size" from "m" to "XXL"
        $cart_item_data['variation']['attribute_pa_size'] = 'xxl';
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

For other products it's something much more complicated and it's really not useful.

Comment: thanks Loic. this is how i can access the size attribute:
$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[$key]['data']->get_data()['attributes']['size']

Comment: is there a way i can set it in one line like this? i tried your code, didn't work

Comment: i was hoping this would work:
WC()->cart->get_cart_item($key)->set_attributes( array('size' => 'XL') );

Comment: @HakimDahoune You will not do anything with your way…